# Booting problem after updating the graphic card driver

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, graphics, recovery-mode

I was working with my computer when I received the Nvidia graphics card driver update message and confirmed the update; After that, I stopped working with the computer and left the house. When I came back, my computer was on, but I could not get any image on the monitor.

I waited for a few minutes, but it didn't help, so I kept my finger on the power button and my computer turned off. I'm not sure whether the graphics card driver update is completed or not. After that, when rebooting Ubuntu, a problem occurred and even in recovery mode, I could not access the terminal because the screen would turn off and on every few moments (when I boot to Windows, my graphics card is fine, so it is not a hardware problem )

Is there a solution to remove the graphics card driver without booting Ubuntu and reinstalling the graphics card driver after booting without problems?

Comment: Good start.  Add details of your configuration (Ubuntu version especially) to your question to imporve the chance to get a correct answer.

Comment: You can try booting into safe mode in grub and try debugging the problem from there?